# libpython2.7.a missing many references

Tags: python, ubuntu, gcc, cython

I'm trying to compile a `cython` module with `-static`, but I am getting a lot of errors about missing references in `libpython2.7.a`. For example:

```
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.a(complexobject.o): In function `_Py_c_pow':
    (.text.unlikely+0x507): undefined reference to `pow'
```

I already have the package `build-essential` installed, which is one solution I found on Google.

My work flow is:

```
cython --embed hi.py
gcc hi.c -lpython2.7 -I /usr/include/python2.7 -static
```

What am I missing to be able to link this file statically?

EDIT: Added additional linker options
`gcc hi.c -lpython2.7 -lm -pthread -lzlib -I /usr/include/python2.7 -static`

All the references to undefined functions went away, but ld is saying it can't find lzlib so compilation still fails. Without `-lzlib` I still get some undefined references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your package manager will show you, the library for zlib is `libz.so`, hence you must pass `-lz`.

Added by question owner:
For other's reference all the linker options needed `-lpython2.7 -lm -ldl -lutil -lz -pthread`