# cannot locate symbol "pow" referenced by "libpython2.7.so"

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I'm trying to run a simple Kivy Hello World app on an Android Emulator. I have failed so far.

Here is the full log when trying to run the appliction on the emulator:
http://pastebin.com/xWYv7bug

I tried different NDKs: r9, r9d, r10e bug I get always the same error.

What could be the problem?

Edit:

I also found in the buildozer log the following, which indicates the problem:

> arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid 
>   -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /Users/tmp/android-ndk-r9d/platforms/android-19/arch-arm   -o python.exe \           Modules/python.o \          -L. -lpython2.7 -ldl 
>   -L/Users/tmp/KivyHello/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib
>   -lz       ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'pow' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'atan2' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'exp' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'log' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'cos' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'sin' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '__isfinite' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '__isinf' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'floor' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'frexp' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'modf' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'fmod' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '__isinff' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'sqrt' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '_Py_asinh' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '_Py_log1p' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'cosh' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'sinh' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'tanh' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'tan' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'log10' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'acos' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '_Py_acosh' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'asin' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'atan' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '_Py_atanh' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'ceil' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to '_Py_expm1' ./libpython2.7.so: error: undefined reference to 'fabs' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status make: *** [python.exe] Error 1

Edit2:

Were eventually some libs missing during linking, like mentioned here?:
[libpython2.7.a missing many references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177221/libpython2-7-a-missing-many-references)

Edit3:

Also from the log that could have something with the missing symbol error:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ranlib: file: libpython2.7.a(pymath.o) has no symbols

Comment: I succeeded in building a runnable hello world application using the VM provided by http://kivy.org/#download

Comment: I got the same error from ddms log I think we should change the spec file for requirement or virtual environment path but I couldn't find the solution yet.

Comment: Facing the same issue. :(